# Can I change a WCF method parameter from int data type to long?

Tags: wcf, operationcontract

Let's say I have an existing method in a WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
CustomerInfo GetCustomerInfo(int customerId);
```

It turns out I need to change this to take a **long** as its parameter instead of an **int**. Would that break existing clients? Or is there some implicit conversion that happens?

Comment: It may break (there may be an implicit conversion since it would be a widening conversion).  Should be easy to check.

Comment: Ok, I tested it locally. The intellisense on my client program indicates the method takes an int. It is still received by the service as a long. So it seems to work. But I would still welcome any insightful/informed answers.